# amazon ec2 small instance 32bit , are we able to scale up without OS upgrade?

Tags: amazon-ec2

The standard instance of EC2 is 1.7GB Memory default 32bit Linux OS for example, 
My question is if one day i want to upgrade or "scale-up" to 7.5GB memory server without reinstalling the OS. To better utilise more than 3GB memory, we definitely need a 64 bit server ?  But if i would like to start from a small instance, will it create a lot of trouble if were to upgrade it in the future?

Answer (score 1):

You can move an EBS boot instance from a 32-bit m1.small to a 32-bit c1.medium without reinstalling.

Above that you have to start over with a 64-bit AMI.

Update: EC2 now supports 64 bit on all instance sizes. You life will be much easier if you only use 64 bit across the board.

Answer (score -2):

If you need more than 3GB of RAM you need 64bit server. I think there can be some problems in switching from 32bit to 64bit because even compiled binaries by you are different from system arch (in 64b linux uses ELF64 format for binaries). I don\t know what are your needs but i will choose microinstances (they support 64bit) and get 2 of them to make "balanced" architecture.

I think you should consider RackSpace services:
http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/pricing/

Price/Performance ratio is same but you will get 64bit from the start, so I don't expect so much trouble with upgrade.